# How can an if statement check two cells?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, return-value

I have written this IF statement in Excel (2016):

```
=IF(AND(R2;S2)="No";"No";"Yes")
```

The purpose is for it to took at cell R2 and S2 and checks if the text in the cell has the text "No".
However, it generates a value error, and I cant seems to work out why.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to test each cell inside the AND formula:

```
=IF(AND(R2="No";S2="No");"No";"Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use an array formula and test range at once:

```
=IF(R2:S2="No";"No";"Yes")
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`